# Accessing parent methods in PHP

Tags: php

I've got a `TopLevelClass` that calls `AnotherClass` which has functions. From inside functions, how do you access `some_other_methods()` for `TopLevelClass`?

If it were JavaScript-esque my problem would look like:

```
$this->parent()->parent()->do_something()
```

and it would be equivalent to

```
$this_function->AnotherClass()->LevelClass()->some_other_methods()
```

Comment: Can you give an example showing why you would want to do this?

Comment: Sure. I would like to use a class as, basically, a bus for messages among other classes. So one subclass is, say, Queue(), and in it you can call methods like Queue()->get_item(). There's another that's Work()->do_work(). I'd like to be able to declare and instantiate the classes once in Bus() class and have modules call each other through it. For example, from Work()->do_work() you might call $Bus->queue->get_item(), $Bus->queue->delete_item() or $Bus->notify->item_processed().

Comment: This all works fine. The kicker is that I want to setup a hooks-based interface a la WordPress. So I'd like to have a single do_hook() function call available in the $Bus level. To do that from the Queue, you need to access the methods parent (Queue) parent (Bus).

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what your goal is.  The way I see it, you'd have `class Bus` which, during construction, would instantiate `class Queue` and `class Work`; alternatively, you could make `Bus` a singleton and use `Bus::getInstance()->whatever()` any time you needed to access it.  But again, I'm not 100% sure what you're driving at here.

Comment: I don't really understand, but I think you might want to check out the *Observer pattern*, especially if you are looking to implement hooks.

Comment: These kinds of circular dependencies should be avoided if possible because they can become very hard to debug and maintain. It seems to me in this situation you should extract the `get_item`, `delete_item`, `notify` logic to the `Bus` and pass what you need into `Work` e.g., inside `Bus`: `$this->work->do_work($this->queue->get_item());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using proper inheritance, you just need the `parent` keyword.

```
class foo {
    protected function fooMethod() {}
}
class bar extends foo {
    public function barMethod() {
        parent::fooMethod();
        // technically, you could do the same thing with $this->fooMethod()
        // but this way you also know how to do it with methods that might have
        // the same name as one another, such as parent::__construct()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do two level of parenting? For example, parent::fooMethod()::parent::anotherMethod or parent::parent::anotherMethod()?

Comment: no, for multiple levels of inheritance you will need to have accessing methods in the mid-level class and call that.  If you repeated this pattern with a class named `baz`, then `bazMethod()` would have to call `parent::barMethod()`

Comment: @editor: If you need to access an object's parent's parent's method directly, there is most likely something wrong with your design.

Comment: I tried to explain myself in a comment attached to the question. I am currently re-instantiating classes and I'd like to set them up just once each.

Answer (score 1):

Out the top of my head:

```
parent::some_other_methods();
```

Comment: Does that access the method through the current scope chain or start a new instance of the class?

Comment: It won't create a new instance, because a new instance is not its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You could make AnotherClass extend TopLevelClass with:

```
class AnotherClass extends TopLevelClass {
  // class stuff in here
}
```

This would give AnotherClass access to all the methods in TopLevelClass as well as it's own (subject to Private scope status).

Comment: What happens if there are two conflicting method names? For example, say both have static methods called "do_hooks" -- would you have to rename to make them unique?

Comment: The extended method can still call it's parent with parent::do_hooks().  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php for some examples.